# Python random.sample()

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import random
random.sample(list_variable,number)
```

This code generates

```
Attribute Error:built-in function or method object has no attribute sample.
```

I am a Python beginner. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You are importing `random` function from `random` package. You need to import sample function.

```
from random import sample
sample([1, 20, 3], 2)
```

Or import `random` package and explicitly call sample function like

```
import random
random.sample([1, 20, 3], 2)
```